# Achieve Damascus steel style with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, masking

so I'm modeling a katana, and I would like to give it a proper "Damascus" style to the blade, and I was wondering if it's possible to achieve this in a way that doesn't involve me opening GIMP/Photoshop.

The desired effect is this:
[image: Damascus style knife]

So far I got this material:
[image]
Ignore the red tint.

So my questions are:

1. How to "mask out" the black so I can control it, and apply the Principaled on top of let's say a brushed metal shader.
2. Is there a way I can make the noise/musgrave/voronoi start in stripes and then go wavy? Maybe aWave texture and use a ramp to fade them?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final

[image: final]

### Node setup

Setup is fairly easy to understand. We will use only **Wave Texture** with **Distortion** controlled by vector driven by **Color Ramp**. Then we will use output of this for **Roughness** in **Principled BSDF**.

First **Color Ramp** (left one) can be used to control how many stripes should be on bottom of the mesh and blend between stripes and pattern. Black is straight, white distorted. Second one controls **Roughness** value and here colors are important. Black is shiny, white is matte.

[image: nodes]

### Output of the texture

[image: output]

### Final with UV mapping and mask for blade

[image: final_plus]

Comment: But I think this material is shiny NO matter what the colour is. Btw your solution with the texture is GREAT.

Comment: @JanMatys second Color Ramp. The one near the Principled BSDF directly connected to Roughness value. Change colors there. White is matte, Black is shiny. Double check where you connecting it also ;)

Comment: No, I only wanna say that I dont think that the Roughness is the value the author wanna use imo.

Comment: @JanMatys What else then in your opinion? We do not have spectral rendering capabilities to simulate physics phenomena that occurs during forging process of Damascus steel. So this is the closest he can get without digging into advanced OSL scripting or switching to other renderer.

Comment: Hm, could U provide a .blend file please? Or show the final render on some object. (or both ;) )

Comment: @JanMatys Check my edit. I believe that setup is simple enough to replicate it without need of blend file.