# how i make this damascus look like the reference photo?

Tags: rendering, node-editor

how i make this knife that i made look like the reference photo at the end? i followed a node setup from here [Achieve Damascus steel style with Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120972/achieve-damascus-steel-style-with-cycles) very usefull and understandble i think, but i dont know how to get this thing look like the reference photo , link of the my model https://gamebanana.com/wips/49621 xD

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you trying to create it procedurally? You should use an Image Texture and use it as a Bump Map + as a factor in a Mix Shader

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i used that node setup -_- so isnt a duplicate there isnt explain the thing that i want

Comment: @moonboots yes its a procedural...how i make the image from the procedural?